# PHP mailer sends multiple mails

Tags: php, email

I saw a lot of questions with the same problem but I can't find what's mine. So I have a contact form to ask for an appointment at the dentist office but for some reason it sends the mail multiple times. Sometimes 4x, sometimes 9x, ...

I changed the mailaddres as an example but this is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
*/
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    // Send mail
//    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // Data received from POST request
    $name = stripcslashes($_POST['name']);   
    $phone = stripcslashes($_POST['phone']);
    $email = stripcslashes($_POST['email']);
    $message = stripcslashes($_POST['message']);
    
    
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <email@here.com>' . "\r\n";
    $subject = "Afspraak aanvraag van: " . $name;
    $message = "Naam: " . $name . "<br /><br />Email: " . $email. "<br /><br />Telefoon: " . $phone. "<br /><br />Bericht: " . $message . ";
    mail('email@here.com',$subject,$message,$headers);
    
   if(mail($subject,$message,$headers)) {
        echo "<h3>Sorry, something went wrong.</h3>";
    } else {
        echo "<h3>Thanks for your message <br></h3>";
    }
    
/*
    // SMTP Configuration
   XXXXXX

    // $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';    
    // $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->MsgHTML("Name:" . $name . "<br /><br />Email:" . $email. "<br /><br />Phone:" . $phone. "<br /><br />Messgae:" . $message);

  if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
}
*/
}
?>
```

Comment: You should redirect to another page after sending email. Maybe someone is refreshing post request, so you are sending multiple emails?

Comment: @Robert that sounds very logical to me. How do I add a redirect into the code? 

Comment: Use function `header('Location: your another page url');`. I've just noticed that you inform user about successful email delivery with message 'Sorry, something went wrong'. It may be the possible cause of your problem and people are refreshing post requests.

Comment: @Robert Thanks a lot! This was exactly the problem. When I refreshed the page it sent the mail again. It has been fixed!

Comment: Use `Reply-To` header to set client mail and not yours. See this article: https://karl-voit.at/2021/07/21/reply-to/

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed by redirecting to another page instead of the 'thank you echo message'. People refreshed the page with the result of duplicate mails.

Comment: for alternative. you could use die('Message Sent') to stop the process without redirecting to another page.